# Spring MVC Tiles 3 and ajax integration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

How to ajax call from the body part, where I have used tiles view in spring MVC.
I didn't find any good example, if any body can help.
So far I am able configure and run the tilesview.

```
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass">
        <beans:value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="order" value="0"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Now I want to send ajax request but no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiles works on the server side, whereas Ajax calls are issued from the client (browser) side. There shouldn't be any interference between the two, as they live in separate universes.

The Ajax calls shouldn't target URLs that are mapped to Tiles definitions ; rather, you should develop new endpoints that directly return JSON, XML or whatever your Ajax call expects.

Comment: I have done the configuration with tiles3 and now wondering how to configure for ajax call.  please check original post as I have editing it

Comment: Ajax isn't something you configure with Tiles or even with Spring MVC. Sending an Ajax call involves writing Javascript code in some HTML page - a page that has been assembled by Tiles in your case, but really Ajax and Tiles have nothing to do with each other.
So showing some Spring/Tiles configuration code is just irrelevant here.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/spring-js.html is kind of confusing to me as FlowAjaxTilesView is there